# How does StackOverflow/StackExchange handle cross-domain sessions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-openid, session

The multi-domain approach to a membership implemented at StackOverflow, through Stack Exchange's network seems well beyond just an Open ID.

How are the individual participant's sessions at multiple domains handled as one single session across many, enough to support such a solid inbox and achievements WebSocket?

Is this through many individual sessions which each store a centralized session ID, or is there one session sustained with a concurrent actor or some such means which keeps session(s) so current?

Comment: I believe there is a single central domain where the session is kept and authentication happens. I presume the sockets for the inbox are also to that single domain. There is a post around here somewhere that details there implementation of multi-domain authentication, this is likely a duplicate of that.